# How to update ruby version to 2.5.1?

Tags: apt, software-installation, compiling, ruby, metasploit

When I tried opening metasploit by

```
msfconsole
```

It showed an error

```
rbenv: version `2.5.1' is not installed (set by /opt/metasploit-framework/.ruby-version)
```

I tried

```
rbenv install rbx-2.5.1
```

its showing

```
BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 16.04 using ruby-build 20160602-19-g0c35180)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20180421085159.19307
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20180421085159.19307.log

Last 10 log lines:
Updating files in vendor/cache
Bundle complete! 5 Gemfile dependencies, 11 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
Checking gcc: found
Checking g++: found
Checking bison:./configure:1430:in ``': No such file or directory - bison (Errno::ENOENT)
    from ./configure:1430:in `check_tool_version'
    from ./configure:722:in `check_tools'
    from ./configure:1815:in `run'
    from ./configure:1995:in `<main>'
```

**What to do now?**

Comment: look at this: https://tecadmin.net/install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu/, and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Before all that this `/tmp/ruby-build.20180421085159.19307.log` should be helpful

Comment: The log is showing "Checking for 'llvm-config': not found
ABORT: unable to set up LLVM"

Comment: Now I installed llvm but the error is "it only works with 3.0-3.5" and I got 3.8

Answer (score 0):

try to run this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get i
$ sudo apt-get install libbison-dev bison
```

Then, try again.